# how to resize page back to normal size

Tags: touchpad

I have a dell inspiron mini with floating touch pad bout 4 years old.

I accidentally, by pressing on lower right edge of unit, miniturized the
image on the page. Its so small now i cant see it,this has happed 4 times now.
I need to resize image back to normal full screen !

I do'nt know if its software or hardware issue ??   Can you help ?

Comment: What image? In a browser? What page? Of an HTML document? In an office program? What are we talking about here?

Comment: The question: [I have a dell inspiron mini notebook laptop. I use the touch pad mouse and it (the mouse) somehow zoomed in.?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090421180548AARQJ0h) was answered by scrap104 at Yahoo Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is related to the touch pad probably because you used the touchpad to scroll down whilst holding down the control key, that leads to the image becoming smaller overall, if you revert that action by scrolling up while holding the control key, it should come back to the size you wish.

Is this simply with web pages or is this an issue with all apps that you're running?

Comment: Projjol  ... hello ur aGENiUS ~ ur iDEA WORKed +++ PERFECTly +++ ............ thankyou ~ saved me from touch pad HELL ~ GOD BLESS u

Comment: @fun, glad it worked, cheers.